# How do I fix dynamic tab selection after upgrading from Bootstrap V4 to V5?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, tabs, bootstrap-5

After upgrading from Bootstrap V4 to V5, the following dynamic tab selection code stopped working.

```
var v_screen = 3;
var triggerMap = {
        2: '#open-tab',
        3: '#closed-tab',
        4: '#support-tab',
        5: '#other-tab'
    };
    $(triggerMap[v_screen]).trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/34767
use the following code

```
bootstrap.Tab.getOrCreateInstance($(triggerMap[v_screen])).show();
```

instead of

```
$(triggerMap[v_screen]).trigger('click');
```